# ASP.NET WebMethod returns whole page to JQuery ajax requests

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am building a web application where I am calling a ASP.NET WebMethod from jQuery on click of a textbox. The problem is that it returns me the whole ASPX Page. How can I get just the values returned by the Web Method? This is my code:

```
$("#<%= groupNameTxt.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../UserGroups.aspx/GetGroupList",
        data: "{  }",
        // dataType: "json"
        type: "POST",
        // contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) { 
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) { 
            alert('err');
        }
    });
});
```

This is my WebMethod from CodeBehind

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<Groups> GetGroupList(string mail)
{
    List<Groups> empList = new List<Groups>();
    empList.Add(new Groups() { GroupID = 1, GroupName = "Admins" });
    empList.Add(new Groups() { GroupID = 2, GroupName = "Employees" });
    empList.Add(new Groups() { GroupID = 3, GroupName = "Engineers" });
    empList.Add(new Groups() { GroupID = 4, GroupName = "Managers" });
    empList.Add(new Groups() { GroupID = 5, GroupName = "Assistants" });
    return empList;
}
```

Comment: On which page is the js? Is it on UserGroups.aspx?

Comment: Are you sure it's hitting your webmethod, and that you're not in fact seeing the HTML response of an error page, such as a 404 or 500? Have you checked the response in the console?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose Yes... Its on the same Page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I cannot be sure if its hitting; When I put a break point in WebMethod, Its not hitting. I am not sure if its because another request.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting an error then. As I stated, check the network tab in the console. It will show the full response text and more importantly the HTTP status code.

Comment: Try with url as UserGroups.aspx/GetGroupList

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am getting success; and responseText contains the page itself.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose It returns the page without images

Comment: You have to inspect the `request` and `response` network calls in your browser dev tools. You are already saying **your method is not being hit**, and **that's the issue**. A complete _guess_, because I recall going through similar, is that be wary of `redirect` - e.g. if you have `FriendlyUrls` which, well, redirects your call to a "friendly url" (therefore changing the original request).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass email as parameter as webmethod is expecting a parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../UserGroups.aspx/GetGroupList",
    data: JSON.stringify({ email: "someemail@test.com"}),
    dataType: "json"
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data) { 
        alert('err');
    }
});
```

Also specify `contentType` and `dataType`

Comment: No,,, that's not the problem...  I am getting whole page even if I go through the URL using browser.

Comment: Because you are getting some error that's why page is being returned.

Comment: if I use contentType : "application/json" 
It returns me 500 - Internal Server Error . 
If I use dataType as json, The JQuery ajax fails, but getting the page as response.

Answer (score 0):

The page was returning since it was not hitting the Web Method. The below code will hit the Web Method correctly. Pass in data as shown below.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "UserGroups.aspx/GetGroupList",
            data: '{ mail: "a@a.com"}',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('err');

            }
        });
```

Comment: But I am getting the page itself naa ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Tested it locally. You were passing the data incorrectly. I was wrong about the "../"

Comment: This may work. But, contentType JSON results me Internal Server Error (500). Maybe any setting in web.config ?

Comment: Try with contentType="application/json; charset=utf-8"